# Tablelayoutpanel location inside panel to print

Tags: vb.net, winforms, printing, tablelayoutpanel

i'm trying to print a tablelayoutpanel that's inside a Panel using printdocument.
But when i preview the print the tablelayoutpanel is placed in the top left corner.
I would like to have it where i placed it on the panel.
The labels that are on the panel maintain there position but the tablelayoutpanel isn't.

This is the code i'm using:

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
Dim blackBrush As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.Black)

For Each ctrl As Control In Panel.Controls
e.Graphics.DrawString(ctrl.Text, ctrl.Font, blackBrush, ctrl.Bounds.Location)
Next

For Each ctrl As Control In Tablelayoutpanel.Controls
e.Graphics.DrawString(ctrl.Text, ctrl.Font, blackBrush, ctrl.Bounds.Location)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Dont use `Dim blackBrush As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.Black)`. If you werre going to create your own `SolidBrush` then you should do so with a `Using` statement, so that it will be disposed at the end of the block. Only create your own brush if you have to though. Use system-created brushes if you can: `e.Graphics.DrawString(ctrl.Text, ctrl.Font, Brushes.Black, ctrl.Bounds.Location)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Location` property of each child control in the `TableLayoutPanel` is relative to the `TableLayoutPanel`, but you are printing as through it's relative to the `Panel`. If, for instance, the `TableLayoutPanel` was at (50,50) inside the `Panel` and a `Label` was at (10,10) within it then the `Label` would be at (60,60) relative to the `Panel`, so that's where you'd need to print it. The simplest option is probably to convert each of those controls' `Location` to screen coordinates and then convert that to client coordinates for the `Panel`:

```vb
For Each ctrl As Control In Panel.Controls
    e.Graphics.DrawString(ctrl.Text, ctrl.Font, blackBrush, ctrl.Bounds.Location)
Next

For Each ctrl As Control In Tablelayoutpanel.Controls
    e.Graphics.DrawString(ctrl.Text,
                          ctrl.Font,
                          blackBrush,
                          Panel.PointToClient(Tablelayoutpanel.PointToScreen(ctrl.Bounds.Location)))
Next
```

Comment: The code is working very well but, if i have a TableLayoutPanel with 3 columns, and the first 2 are aligned left and the third one aligned right using, TableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(New Label() With {.Text = "text", .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight}, 2, 1). All is still printed aligned left. Why?

Comment: @Desz, don't ask new questions in comments on accepted answers. If you have a new question, post a new question, with all the information relevant to that question. Keep in mind though, you need to have tried something first. Where in your code are you doing anything to right-align the printed text? Nowhere. Do some research on how to actually do that first.

Comment: you're right! it won't happen again. i posted a new question, maybe you can take a look, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67657984/tablelayoutpanel-right-aligned-text-not-printing, thank you!