# TableLayoutPanel right aligned text not printing

Tags: vb.net, winforms, printing, tablelayoutpanel

I'm trying to print a TableLayoutPanel with 3 columns, the first two columns need to be left aligned and the third one right aligned.
I'm creating labels inside the TableLayoutpanel using the following code:

```
TableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(New Label() With {.Text = "1000 meter", .AutoSize = False, .Width = 150, .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight}, 2, 1)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thank you for your time!

**UPDATE:**

I've added `.Dock = DockStyle.Fill` to the label and i'm using this code:

```
 Dim sf = New StringFormat()
 sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
 For Each ctrl As Control In TableLayoutPanel.Controls
 e.Graphics.DrawString(ctrl.Text, ctrl.Font, Brushes.Black, Panel.PointToClient(TableLayoutPanel.PointToScreen(ctrl.Bounds.Location)), sf)
 Next
```

Now everything is aligned right, but i only need the last column to align right.
Thank you!

Comment: I told you in your previous question that you needed to do some research first and it appears that you haven't. If you had read the documentation for the `DrawString` method that you're already using to print text then you would know that it allows you to specify alignment within an area. Given that you are already using the location of the `Label`, it should be obvious that the area you want to align within is the bounds of the `Label`.

Comment: Could you please give me an example? i've already tried using  sf.LineAlignment=StringAlignment.Far and sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far but it's not working for me.

Comment: Set the labels `Dock` properties to `DockStyle.Fill` and the `AutoSize` properties to `false`. This way you'll get the bounds of the cell when you print and the text in the last column will be aligned correctly. Set `sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;` to align left, and `sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;` to align right.

Comment: thank you for your comment!, i've updated the question with what's happening now. Do you have any idea how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Ohh. What a mess we've made here! Now ignore my first comment and try the following: in the `For Each` add a first line: `sf.Alignment = If(TableLayoutPanel.GetColumn(ctrl) < 2, StringAlignment.Near, StringAlignment.Far)`. and keep the rest. And dispose of the `sf` after the `For Each` block. `sf.Dispose()`

Comment: Thank you so much! the alignment is great, but why is everything in the label properties  ignored? autosize = false and width = 100? It sees to work but not when i print it, or must i create another question? thank you!